# MySQL: SELECT EXISTS() AS field WHERE field = x

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, mysql-error-1054

The problem: 
I have an inventory table, and a table listing items that are being auctioned off. I want to have an alias field ("isAuction") to represent whether or not an item with inventory's stock number is present in the auction items table.

I wrote the following Query:

```
SELECT FROM inventory AS i
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auctionitems AS a WHERE a.stockNo = i.stockNo) AS "isAuction"
```

This does populate "isAuction" field with 1 or 0, as required.

I now add a WHERE condition:

```
SELECT FROM inventory AS i
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auctionitems AS a WHERE a.stockNo = i.stockNo) AS "isAuction" 
WHERE isAuction = 1
```

However, when I add a WHERE condition, I get an error:
"#1054 - Unknown column 'isAuction' in 'where clause'"

Two questions:
1) Where did I get it wrong?
2) Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `HAVING isAuction = 1`.

I read somewhere that HAVING is more awake of calculated columns than WHERE.

Comment: Yep in MySQL that's true. The alias isn't really needed here though as the usual way of writing this is as per Richard's answer.

Comment: This is the best solution for me here, as it allows me to keep "isAuction" column. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM inventory AS i
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auctionitems AS a WHERE a.stockNo = i.stockNo)
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work. Same error. I'm testing with PHP MyAdmin, btw.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use aliases in `WHERE`. You can do

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auctionitems AS a WHERE a.stockNo = i.stockNo)
```

Or you can put a condition into `HAVING` clause (mysql lets you use `HAVING` without aggregate functions) :
`HAVING isAuction = 1`
Also, you can write

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT i.*,
 EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auctionitems AS a WHERE a.stockNo = i.stockNo) AS isAuction 
 FROM inventory AS i

)a
WHERE a.isAuction = 1
```

Comment: I guess that should have been "HAVING" instead of "WHERE" in the code. But yes, HAVING is the solution for me.

Comment: `WHERE` also works in the last example because the query uses subquery in `FROM` clause. But you are right, in this case it's just an equivalent to `HAVING` - it first grabs all rows from DB, and later filters results which is different from how 'normal' `WHERE` works (it filters records while getting them from the table)